# POD structure of array

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, parallel-processing, structure

I am trying to wrap my mind around SOA [structure of arrays] in c programming.

I have some simple math functions which I have written what I believe is pretty decent scalar implementations.

here is a simple vector 3 data structure

```
struct vector3_scalar {
    float p[3];
};
```

and a typical function that I have written to add two of these vector 3 data structures.

```
struct vector3_scalar* vec3_add(struct vector3_scalar* out,
                                const struct vector3_scalar* a,
                                const struct vector3_scalar* b) {
    out->p[0] = a->p[0] + b->p[0];
    out->p[1] = a->p[1] + b->p[1];
    out->p[2] = a->p[2] + b->p[2];

    return out;
}
```

I know this simple data structure isn't padded correctly but for scalar I just wanted to get something that worked first before I started implementing other features.

now my question, is that structure 'sans padding issues' a good way to setup the data structure?

what about these instead?

```
struct vector3_scalar {
    float p[3];
};


struct vector3_scalar {
    float px;
    float py;
    float pz;
};
```

or any other way that I could lay out the data. I personally don't mind flipping the data structures since  users of this math shouldn't have to go this low and mess with this code once it has been written and optimized, just the higher level functions such as;

```
vec3 *a = vec3_create(0, 1, 0);
vec3 *b = vec3_create(1, 0, 0);
vec3 *c = vec3_zero(void);

vec3* vec3_add(vec3* out, const vec3* in_a, const vec3* in_b);

c = vec3_add(c, a, b); // c == 1, 1, 0
```

so that you can  use the function inline or by itself.

```
vec3 *d = vec3_create(10, 10, 10);
vec3 *e = vec3_create(1, 1, 1);
vec3 *f = vec3_zero();

/* c + d = 11, 11, 10 */  /* c + e = 2, 2, 1 */
vec3_add(f, vec3_add(c, d), vec3_add(c, e));

vec3_free(a);
...
vec3_free(f);
```

so as you can see from the public api, the underlying structures shouldn't really matter except for the implementer.

I would like to write the basic scalar version which I already wrote using the data layout like this:

```
struct vector3_scalar {
     float p[3];
}
```

but I am open to changing that now that it works and seems stable enough for my taste.

Comment: Based upon what you've shown, without any additional context, it doesn't matter much if you use discrete values `px`, `py`, `pz` or an array, `p[3]`. I'm not sure what you mean by "padding issues". I don't see any issues with either approach. Are you having a specific problem? If not, then this question is largely opinion based or should be in the codereview.stackexchange.com area.

Comment: What are these hypothetical 'padding issues'?  Don't fret about them; the compiler lays things out optimally.  People who get antsy about padding are either careless in the design of their structures or are trying to force the in-memory representation of a file or wire format to exactly match the bytes in the file or wire format.  There' no evidence that's a problem here.  In both your data structures, there is no padding (or it is unlikely you have a compiler that introduces any, though a compiler theoretically could, but practically would not).

Comment: padding is data aligning typically to 16, 32, 64 or 128 bit alignment for cache coherency typically when dealing with parallel data operations like SIMD devices.

Comment: I suspect you've misunderstood the difference between AOS and SOA. If you're using "arrays" of 3 values to represent e.g. coordinates in three-dimensional space, you're not using structs of arrays, you're using arrays of structs.

Comment: @EOF I am sure that I misunderstand AOS and SOA, that's the root of the question. I've searched a lot and hear mention of it but not much solid documentation. Do you have any references that I can check out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are AoS representations, not SoAs:

```
struct vector3_scalar {
    float p[3];
};

struct vector3_scalar {
    float px;
    float py;
    float pz;
};
```

They're the exact same thing, and aligned and padded the same. For example, on mine, `sizeof(vector3_scalar) == 12` (size of 3 floats).

If we're talking about AoS vector representations, the former can be beneficial for communicating with C APIs, e.g., that want to accept a pointer to float, and also can help avoid redundant code by allowing you to loop through the vector components.

An SoA would look like this:

```
struct vector4
{
     float x[4];
     float y[4];
     float z[4];
};
```

It would represent each field as a separate array, and often with a size multiple of 4 for SIMD.

In this case, `sizeof(vector4) == 48/4 == 12`. We don't get any memory savings benefit here as there's no padding for `vector3_scalar`. Nevertheless, the SoA rep is more conducive to SSE which wants to use 128-bit registers and benefits from aligned memory. In that case, we'd have to introduce a 4th component into `vector3_scalar` to be able to directly load it into an XMM register, making a single vector take 16 bytes instead of 12. Moreover, depending on what you are doing, an AoS rep may require more horizontal/shuffle type operations which aren't always so fast with SIMD, while the SoA rep can just vectorize the operations very trivially one component type at a time.

But let's take an example like this:

```
struct Person
{
    int y;
    char x;
};
```

In this case, `sizeof(Person) == 8` on mine which means 3 bytes worth of padding were added for alignment. If we use an SoA rep:

```
struct Persons
{
    int y[4];
    char x[4];
};
```

... `sizeof(Persons) == 20`. `20 / 4 == 5`. So now we have 5 bytes per person instead of 8 bytes per person while still having each field aligned properly.

As to whether this is beneficial from a performance perspective and not merely a memory savings perspective, it depends a lot on which fields are hot/cold, the number of persons, etc. You could also use an AoSoA:

```
struct Persons
{
    struct Person4
    {
        int y[4];
        char x[4];
    };
    Person4 persons_x4[n/4];
};
```

That tends to balance things out quite nicely since it doesn't degrade spatial locality linearly between fields for the same person as `n` gets larger and larger.

Comment: This is the best answer i've seen on this question on SO. I went to the intel forums to get a little more help but this is very nicely explained. I want to do this fro graphics programming, the core low level stuff that no one should mess with once it's all set up. Currently though I am using scalar versions of all those data structures and will keep on learning more about this to be able to write efficient SSE/NEON code for the core math operations.

Comment: @user1610950 A lot of the hard part is just from the design perspective. SoAs can be really fast but they're awkward to use -- often productivity becomes just as much of a concern as efficiency there.. so a lot of the challenge can be just building a high-level interface that can let people do things using scalar logic, e.g., when the code isn't so performance-critical.. while opting into those SIMD routines when they want max speed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not both?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct {
    union {
        float as_arr[3];
        struct {
            float px;
            float py;
            float pz;
        };
    };
} my_point;

int main (void)
{
    my_point.as_arr[1] = .5;
    printf ("%f\n", my_point.py);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have trouble understanding what padding actually is. It is just an optimisation done automatically by the compiler.

Due to some hardware/architectural reasons, multiple bytes are fetched at a time from memory. Let's say 4, which is quite common for today's architecture. Also, you can't fetch form memory any 4 consecutive bytes. The address of the first byte must be divisible by 4.

Now, assume the following structure:

```
struct x {
   char a;
   int b;
};
```

Let's assume we have an instance of x that has address 100. So, in the byte at address 100 you will store a, and whenever you operate on a, you fetch bytes 100, 101, 102, 103.

Now let's thing what happens with b. If b would start immediately after a (i.e. at address 101), 2 fetches would be required. First, fetch bytes 100, 101, 102, 103, then fetch 104, 105, 106, 107 and then do some computations to get the integer, which is stored on bytes 101-104. In order to avoid this, the compiler will insert 3 bytes of padding after a, which will make your structure occupy 8 bytes, instead of 5 as you would expect. But notice that this is just a performance optimisation (trading memory space for execution time basically), and unless you have lots of instances or do some very advanced things, it wouldn't matter for you.

Also, in your case, the declarations of your structures are, from a memory perspective, equivalent.